# How can you set two eruvin? It's making your residence in two places!

Tags: eruv-chatzerot, eruv-techumin

The introduction of ר׳ פנחס קהתי's to מסכת ערובין reads, in part (in my own translation and with emphasis supplied):

> … that residents of the courtyard not carry from their houses to the courtyard or from the courtyard to their houses unless they made an "*eruv [chatzeros]*", i.e. that all the residents place food before the sabbath in the house of one of their number. By doing so their domain becomes combined, **they themselves are as if they're all concentrated in the residence in which the *eruv* food is placed**, and the entire courtyard with its houses becomes as if one homogeneous domain.…
>
> … makes an "*eruv t'chumim*" before the sabbath, i.e. that he places… two meals' food, thereby acquiring sabbathhood at that location when the sabbath starts, meaning that **we look upon the location where he left the *eruv* as if it's his house for this sabbath**…

My kid asked: Why is it possible for someone to make both an *eruv chatzeros* and an *eruv t'chumin*? It's setting his residence in two different places for the same sabbath and shouldn't work. [I might add that the same applies to making two *eruve chatzeros*.] We've never heard that's impossible.

Comment: Interestingly, there's an [OK article](http://www.ok.org/kosherspirit/winter-2011/eruv-defining-space/) which states "If one is making both an *eruv chatzeros* and an *eruv techumim* together, there are opinions that one should amend the *brocha* to plural, or to spell out the specific *eruvim* (*eruv chatzeros v’eruv techumim*)", yet the [source they give](http://www.ok.org/kosherspirit/winter-2011/eruv-defining-space/#13) makes no mention of *eruv techumim*!

Comment: Two topics. Eruvin chatserot is for tiltul, to restaure the status of standard reshut hayochid after the isur derabanan with chatserot. Eruv tchumin is to get away from the techum. It's, following some tanayim, and Rambam rules as this shita. From the home to the eruv, 2000 ama, from the eruv to the new limit of tchum 2000 ama.

Comment: If the Techum one is real, would he even need to participate in the Chatzerot one since he doesn't live in the Chatzer? (At least theoretically speaking; it could be lo plug)

Comment: Maybe he can't make them on the same Shabbos? All the Kehati writes is that there are two Eruvin; he doesn't say about doing both of them at the same time.

Comment: @doubleAA Yes because as he did get away he can come back to the chatser

Comment: My guess would be that _eruv chatzeros_ joins the houses, independent of the individual, whereas _eruv t'chumin_ is for the individual. (So you now have a luxurious co-joined _camping ground_ you slept in, and for this Shabbat your permanent residence is under the open sky in the middle of nowhere.)

Answer (score 3):

To address your bracketed query regarding making two *eruvei chatzerot*, [Aruch HaShulchan, Orach Chayyim 372:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.372.15?lang=bi) writes:

> בית העומדת בין שתי חצרות, שכל אחת עירבה לעצמה והוא עירב עם שתיהן - יכול לטלטל לכאן ולכאן כל דבר. ואין לומר איך אדם דר בשני מקומות, דאין זה שאלה, דכל אדם יש לו רשות לדור ולאכול בכמה מקומות, וכולם חשובים אצלו דירות.‏
>
> A house which is in between two courtyards, each one having made its own *eruv*, and [the inhabitant of this house] makes an *eruv* with both of them, he may carry anything to both courtyards.
>
> Don't ask, "How can someone live in two places?" This is no question, because every person can live and eat in multiple places, all of which are considered his houses.

As far as your primary question regarding creating both an *eruv techumin* and *eruv chatzerot*, I would posit that the same holds true. One can create a residence at the time *shabbat* starts in the place where one places one's *eruv techumin*, while simultaneously having another residence (to be used later on during *shabbat*) in the courtyard for the purposes of creating an *eruv chatzerot*.

Comment: מחלוקת רב לשמואל מקום פיתה או מקום לינה. הלכה מקום פיתה

Comment: But we don't find that you can establish multiple Techum boxes by planting many Eruvei Techumin in different directions

Comment: @DoubleAA - because your techum is set by your residence **at the start of shabbat**.

Comment: Oh I missed that in your answer. Chatzerot works the same way though. You can eat the eruv right after nightfall. No eruv cares where you live later that day

Comment: @DoubleAA You can eat it after nightfall because when shabbat started, you had fixed that place as one of your residences for shabbat. Maybe you were going to live there in two hours time, or maybe in twenty. Once shabbat has commenced, that status can't be removed, whatever happens to the food. However (I suggest) eruv techumin needs to be defined as your residence at *kenisat shabbat*, so multiple eiruvei techumin are impossible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between them. Eruv t'chumin establishes your residency for this shabbos. While, eruv chatzeros establishes your ownership or actually gives up your ownership rights for other to use.
Its easier to image when you are owner of 2 houses. You decide to spend the shabbos in house A but your neighbors from house B are asking if their kids can play in your backyard of house B?
So your eruv t'chumin is in house A while the neighbors from house B need you to relinquish your ownership rights for them to carry in your rightful property there.
The best example is a bungalow colony where there are communal areas such as playground and all the owners have part in it and therefore no one can carry from their private bungalow to a shared space. The way around is to create eruv chatzeros by relinquish their personal rights to the communal space and thereby making into 1 owner property.